# How to find which pages are attached to a Dreamweaver template

Tags: file, templates, dreamweaver, locate

I have a site with several Templates (.dwt)

Two questions:

Is there a way to easily find which pages or files are attached to a specific template without having to open every file?

Is there a way to update only selected files attached to a template?

Answer (score 2):

This page has a whole lot of info on working with templates:

[Dreamweaver Template Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7a9da.html)

To find all pages that use a specific template you can do a search (command+f or control+f) for `<!-- InstanceBegin template="/Templates/***YourTemplateName***.dwt.php"`, make sure to to choose Entire site from the first drop down...
[image]

...and Source Code from the second
[image]

You can update an open file by choosing Modify -> Templates -> Update Current page